# Could not find class 'android.transition.Transition'

Tags: android, gradle, logcat

I have an android app with only one activity and 7 Fragments inisde the activity, I dont know why every time I change between Fragments it throws the following error:

The app doesnt crash, but I think it is slowing it.

**The logcat is throwing this error:**

```
08-17 21:21:49.637 27378-27378/com.limecream.myday E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.transition.Transition', referenced from method com.limecream.myday.configuracionFragmento.access$super
08-17 21:21:49.657 27378-27378/com.limecream.myday E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.transition.Transition', referenced from method com.limecream.myday.configuracionFragmento.access$super
08-17 21:21:49.667 27378-27378/com.limecream.myday E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.app.SharedElementCallback', referenced from method com.limecream.myday.configuracionFragmento.access$super
08-17 21:21:49.677 27378-27378/com.limecream.myday E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.transition.Transition', referenced from method com.limecream.myday.configuracionFragmento.access$super
08-17 21:21:49.677 27378-27378/com.limecream.myday E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.transition.Transition', referenced from method com.limecream.myday.configuracionFragmento.access$super
08-17 21:21:49.677 27378-27378/com.limecream.myday E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.app.SharedElementCallback', referenced from method com.limecream.myday.configuracionFragmento.access$super
08-17 21:21:49.687 27378-27378/com.limecream.myday E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.transition.Transition', referenced from method com.limecream.myday.configuracionFragmento.access$super
08-17 21:21:49.697 27378-27378/com.limecream.myday E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.transition.Transition', referenced from method com.limecream.myday.configuracionFragmento.access$super
```

**here is my gradle:**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '22.0.1'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.limecream.myday"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:1.2.1'
    compile 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.9'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.0'
    compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library-aar:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.makeramen:roundedimageview:2.2.1'
    compile 'net.gotev:uploadservice:2.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
}

android {
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
}
```

What is wrong?

Comment: Transition class was added in `API LEVEL 19`. Your min sdk is `15`. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/transition/Transition.html. You should probably be applying a transition when you change fragments

Comment: @JaswanthManigundan it could slow the app this error in a 16 sdk?

Comment: I think, the app tries to find the class Transition in sdk 16 and then fails to add the transition. This might cause the delay in fragment transition. Try to remove the transition and test the time delay. It will help you find the problem.

Comment: @JaswanthManigundan the thing is that I dont know exactly what is the fragment transition, could you guide me a little?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26747828/could-not-find-class-android-transition-transition-exception-when-pressing-bac. Looks like this happens in devices <19 as I mentioned earlier. Nothing to do with your code I guess.

Comment: @JaswanthManigundan  FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
                FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                Fragment fragment = new trazarRutaFragmento();
                transaction.replace(R.id.contenedor, fragment);
                transaction.commit();

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121217/discussion-between-jaswanth-manigundan-and-gustavo-serna).

Comment: @GustavoSerna Try changing "getFragmentManager()" to  "getSupportFragmentManager()" and see if the same issue happens.